# What is the difference between FB.api and FB.Data.query

Tags: javascript, facebook

From what I gather the following two will bring back the same result

FB.api

```
FB.api('/'+user_id, function(response){
   document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'Your name is ' + respone.name;
});
```

FB.Data.Query

```
var query = FB.Data.query('select name, uid from user where uid={0}',user_id);
query.wait(function(rows) {
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML =
  'Your name is ' + rows[0].name;
});
```

So what is the difference between these two, what case would one be preferable over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs,

> [FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) makes API calls to the Graph API or Deprecated REST API.
>
> [FB.Data.Query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Data.query/) performs a parameterized FQL query and returns a FB.Data.query object which can be waited on for the asynchronously fetched data.

Basically you can use FB.Data.Query when you want to perform some kind of an advanced query using FQL. Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

Comment: So FB.api is not async?  I have to wait for the whole call to be completed before I can use the fetched data?

Comment: Both are async, the difference is FB.Data.Query lets you do more advanced stuff, like batching requests.. Read the FQL page for more info.